# Android app x11 forwarding to computer

Tags: applications, ssh

I have "SSH Server" app installed. I'm able to connect and launch apps using `am`. I want to forward the apps through X11 forwarding to my linux computer. Is that possible?

There is a "X11 forwarding" configuration in "SSH Server" that I have enabled, although I have no idea what the effect is.

So far, when I connect to the phone I get:

```
$ ssh -X user@phone
user@phone's password: 
X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0
u0_a107@phone:/ $
```

So it seems I have some extra issue with X11.

Anyone has tried this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do is not possible. Android has its own windowing system, not X11, so X forwarding won't do anything on Android.

There are other screen-sharing systems (such as VNC) which might be more suitable for what you're trying to do. [This answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/77270/12442) talks about a Samsung-specific app, and [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/38850/12442) has a couple of options. The [remote-access](/questions/tagged/remote-access) and [remote-control](/questions/tagged/remote-control) tags have a lot more information.